# Compare dates in VBA Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a database with a table that has the current appointments for interviews, tblSchedule which has the following columns RNName, Apttime, Aptdate, PtID.

I'm trying to not allow duplicate appointments.

I want to run an sql code in VBA so when a new appointment date is entered on the form I can check to see if the date is already in the table and if it is in the table it will limit the times that are available to select.

I'm having problems with the date comparison. It works in a saved sql query in Access but when I try the same query in VBA I get no results.

VBA code

```vb
Private Sub Apt_date_AfterUpdate()
Dim check As DAO.Recordset
Dim time_sql As String
Dim count_sql As Long
Dim sql_1 As String
Dim Aptday As Date
Aptday = DateValue(Forms("booking_clerk").Apt_date.Value)

Forms("booking_clerk").Apt_time.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Forms("booking_clerk").Apt_time.RowSource = ""

Set check = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select DateValue(tblSchedule.Aptdate) From tblSchedule WHERE DateValue(tblSchedule.Aptdate)" & " = (" & Aptday & "); ")

count_sql = check.RecordCount

MsgBox (Str(count_sql))

If check.RecordCount = 0 Then
    time_sql = "SELECT Field1 FROM [Pam Availability];"
Else: time_sql = ("SELECT Field1 FROM [Pam Availability]WHERE [Pam Availability].Field1 Not In  (Select tblSchedule.Apttime from tblSchedule WHERE DateValue(tblSchedule.Aptdate) = (" & Aptday & "));")

End If

Forms("booking_clerk").Apt_time.RowSource = time_sql

End Sub
```

The saved sql code. I enter the date as a parameter here:

```
SELECT DateValue(tblSchedule.Aptdate) AS Expr1
FROM tblSchedule
WHERE DateValue(tblSchedule.Aptdate) = DateValue([new_date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the proper syntax for concatenating date values in Access SQL:

```
Set check = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select DateValue(tblSchedule.Aptdate) From tblSchedule WHERE DateValue(tblSchedule.Aptdate) = #" & Format(Aptday, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```

Answer (score 0):

While Gustav did point out your error, you are doing way too much work to try and get at a simple lookup issue. I try to avoid recordsets where I can, but thats probably due to how I was taught/trained over the years. Either way, it is a good habit to question why youre approaching a certain task the way your are. What benefit does a recordset bring to this situation? I mean honestly it just created more work than it was worth.

Anyway, ill get off my soap box now.

```
Private Sub Apt_date_AfterUpdate()
    Dim time_sql As String

    Forms("booking_clerk").Apt_time.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    Forms("booking_clerk").Apt_time.RowSource = ""
    
    IF Dcount("DateValue(tblSchedule.Aptdate)", "tblSchedule", "DateValue(tblSchedule.Aptdate)=#" & DateValue(Forms("booking_clerk").Apt_date.Value) & "#;") = 0 Then
        time_sql = "SELECT Field1 FROM [Pam Availability];" 
    Else
        time_sql = "SELECT Field1 "
        time_sql = time_sql & "FROM [Pam Availability] "
        time_sql = time_sql & "WHERE [Pam Availability].Field1 "
        time_sql = time_sql & "Not In  (Select tblSchedule.Apttime from tblSchedule "
        time_sql = time_sql & "WHERE DateValue(tblSchedule.Aptdate) = #" & DateValue(Forms("booking_clerk").Apt_date.Value) & "#); "    
    End if
    
    Forms("booking_clerk").Apt_time.RowSource = time_sql    
    
End Sub
```